# Button not animating from center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So when I used jquery to animate some padding instead of animation as if the anchor point is from the center it animates from the top left. All the code and a JSFiddle link are down below.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ky3fjfer/)

HTML:

```
<div id="gaming-news-info">
    <a id="news-button" style="cursor:pointer;">Go to News section</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gaming-news-info {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#news-button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
    font-family: "Prompt-SemiBold";
    margin-left: 90px;
}
```

Comment: I'd not use javascript/jquery at all... https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/ky3fjfer/1/

Comment: That worked, put as a answer so I can say it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need jquery/javascript for a simple hover effect. CSS3 transitions and transformations are perfectly capable of doing the same thing without the overhead of a script library....

```css
#gaming-news-info {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 margin-top: -100px;
}

#news-button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
    font-family: "Prompt-SemiBold";
   margin-left: 90px;
 transform: scale(1);
 transition: all .2s;
}

#news-button:hover {
 transform: scale(1.05);
 transition: all .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="gaming-news-info">
  <a id="news-button" style="cursor:pointer;">Go to News section</a>
</div>
```